# Will the parent component execute the beforeUpdate/update hook function when child mounted?

Tags: vue.js

When the child component was mounted, will the parent component execute the beforeUpdate/update hook function?

Answer (score 0):

VueJS uses bottom up approach so child components runs first. and parent component collect all child component at last.

So if child wants to listen somting from parent they have register fist by `on` function and parent says by `emit` function.

And child can set parent elements also by saying `$parent` but its not recommended because other child can overwrite this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is that when the child component was mounted, will the parent component execute the beforeUpdate/update hook function in vue? I try some demo, but I didn't print the message in beforeUpdate/update function.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not execute.

beforeUpdate/update hooks work after component is mounted:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Parent component could not be mounted while its children not mounted.

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/2fg1vetx/

```
const Child = {
  template: '<span>i am "Child" component</span>',
  mounted() {
    console.log('Child is mounted');
  },
};

const Parent = {
  components: { Child },
  template: '<child />',
  beforeUpdate() {
    console.log('Parent beforeUpdate');
  },
  update() {
    console.log('Parent update');
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Parent is mounted');
  },
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Parent },
});
```